# Remotely delete recent files history

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I want to delete the recent files history that can be found when you open File Explorer (in Windows 10). I want to do it using cmd, so that I can do it in all the computers on my network without going one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: Thanks! Am I able to delete a file from a computer in my network remotely (I have administrator privileges)?

Comment: I'd recommend you to deploy the script either via GPO or a software delivery solution (if in place).
If you really want to do it from your pc/server you would have to know all the user profiles which are currently active on the destination machine, which I assume you don't.

Comment: You could also save the Script to a network location and send your users a link to click  ;-)